# Can't program in any block connected to a drop-off due to the following error

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I'm trying to model a bus drop-off and set a counter for the availability of a shelter. Any time I try to program at the *on enter* of the sink following the drop-off this error keeps showing up.[image]

Every single block of the line following the drop-off has been configured with the correct agent type contained in the container agent.

Comment: How is your Dropoff configured?

Comment: While condition is true

Comment: I  meant "pls share a screen of your Dropoff condition" :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your "Element type" in the Dropoff properties is set to the agent type that your `Sink` also expects (`Personas`)